# NonlinearModelFit: fit a vector-valued function to a data vector

Tags: fitting

I have a vector of data points:

```
data = 10 Sin[#/10] + RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[] & /@ 
   Range[200];
```

And I have model that provides the complete data vector as value

```
matrix = Table[i (Sin[j/10]), {i, 20}, {j, 200}];
weights[a_] := Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[a, 1], i], {i, Range@20}];
model[a_] := weights[a].matrix;
```

`model[10]` is a good approximation of data.

They way I currently determine the fit parameters is by using `FindMinimum` and explicitly minimize the fit penalty:

```
FindMinimum[
 Total[(data - model[a])^2],
 {{a, 10}}
 ]
```

This works nice. But the evaluation of fit statistics like error volumes is very tedious because the underlying matrix and the model function is rather complex.
When fitting with `NonlinearModelFit` instead, a lot of those statistics are readily available. But I have struggled to adapt it accordingly:

Something like

```
NonlinearModelFit[
 data,
 model[a],
 {{a, 1}},
 var
 ]
```

Unfortunately, there are problems. Can it be adapted? I dont actually need any variables to fit the expressions.

Kind regards

Comment: Doesn't `NonlinearModelFit[
 data,
 model[a],
 {{a, 10}},
 var, Method -> "NMinimize"
 ]` return the same or a better solution than your `FindMinimum`?

Answer (score 4):

I think using Quantile regression might do what you want. Quantile regression uses a minimization algorithm and if the fitting functions are B-splines you do not need to specify a model.

Similar problem and solution are discussed in more detail in [Find Fit for Non-linear data](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/find-fit-for-non-linear-data/) .

If you really want to use the vectors of the matrix then you can use `QuantileRegressionFit` in the package linked below. (That is not straightforward, though. The matrix have to be converted into a list of functions, by say interpolation. I can work this solution out if it is of interest.)

The following steps apply Quantile regression with B-splines for the data in the question.

First, get the [QuantileRegression.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/QuantileRegression.m) package from [MathematicaForPrediction at GitHub](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]
```

Do the data generation with the command in the question:

```
data = 10 Sin[#/10] + RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[] & /@ Range[200];
```

Add t-axis:

```
data = Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}];
```

Find the regression quantile using B-splines of 2nd order:

```
qfunc = Simplify[
   QuantileRegression[data, 12, {0.5}, InterpolationOrder -> 2][[1]]];
```

Plot the data and the fitted curve:

```
dGr = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
qfGr = Plot[qfunc[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}];
Show[{dGr, qfGr}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]
Here is the fitted function after using `PiecewiseExpand` and `Simplify`:

```
qfunc = Evaluate[Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[qfunc[[1]]]]] &;
qfunc
```

[image]

Here is an example of approximation error statistics:

```
ListPlot[Map[{#[[1]], (qfunc[#1[[1]]] - #1[[2]])/#1[[2]]} &, data], 
 Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, I think you are making things more difficult then they need be by calculating model fits in `matrix`. It seems you have already determined that the form of your model is $b \sin[\frac{x}{10}]$ and they you just need to fit $b$. This is exactly what `NonlinearModelFit` does.  So you don't need to calculate out `matrix` and do your own minimisation function.

All that is needed is the data and the form.

```
data = 10 Sin[#/10] + RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[] & /@ Range[200];
fm = NonlinearModelFit[data, b Sin[x/10], {b}, x]
fm["BestFitParameters"]
fm["RSquared"]
```

Since `data` is a vector then it is fitted against successive x values (1, 2, ...).  This is the first type of call listed in [`NonlinearModelFit`'s documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html). The fitted values and all the fit statistics are in `fm`.  See the documentation for how to access them.  I've tried a few executions and get very close to b -> 10 with perfect r-squared.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the simple case of the example is not present in my real problem. There, the function to be fitted is not a sine wave but the result of a multidimensional convolution integral. Calculating all of those integrals using the explicit form NIntegrate is extremely time consuming. A fast way is to replace all the convolutions by dot products weighing a high-dimensional tensor of possible function values. This tensor is called "matrix" in my example and the individual convolutions are performed by  dot-mulitcation by a weighting vector "weights".