# Filtering Background with resonance or Peaks

Tags: plotting, fitting, filtering, peak-detection

[image]

I have some data, the blue curve which I want to filter out the  background to get a flat signal with dips(Idea is to divide signal (except the dips) by the background). The orange curve is my best fit so far. You can see that it agrees for most of the points, apart from the deviation at around 1000. Otherwise, the fitting was very good. and It almost returned a noiseless result by dividing the blue curve (raw data) by the fitting.

I expect something like below[image]
However, the problem was that my fitting also has dips (which i don't want to divide out my dip!),also since the background was changing constantly, using a higher order fitting function returns wiggles, so it makes it really hard to have no wiggles between the dips.
Here is the bad example,again, the blue = raw data, orange = fitting, green = processed data.
[image]

And I want something like this, where the blue curve sorts of fill the gap[image: ![enter image description here]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgH8A.png)
Any ideas how to do this?
I tried using lowpass filter, doesn't work. What i'm using now is Peak detect/ find peak method.
I also tried Fourier transform and remove higher k components, but it doesn't work! I appreciate for any idea ! And I can write the code myself.

Comment: You could create an interpolating function on the data with the dips excluded, i.e. find peak positions, extract all data within +/-N of peak, interpolate and then sample your interpolation function at all data points and use this to divide out background. Low pass filtering, or moving average before fitting, etc. should also be ok. without access to the data it's going to be tough to help.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide the data.

Comment: You can use Quantile Regression for this as explained [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94750/34008).

Comment: N.J.Evans. That's exactly How i did it. But it fitted the gaps between peaks with a dip which is something i don't want.

Comment: Quantile Regression failed

Comment: @elpsyCongroo In what way Quantile regression failed? Convergence or you do not like the result? What parameters did you tried? As others mentioned, this discussion would be much easier if you share your data...

Answer (score 2):

One quick approximation uses the compound median filter defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104950/detecting-components-in-timeseries/105017#105017).

I converted the blue line in your image to a vector of amplitudes `trace`. The orange line is the filtered output, the green line is the residual. Vary the second input parameter of `CompoundMedianFilter` to see other baseline approximations.

```
ListLinePlot[{trace, CompoundMedianFilter[trace, 15], 
              trace - CompoundMedianFilter[trace, 15]},
             Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-180, 280}]
```

[image: baseline subtraction]

Comment: It's not supposed to be block function

Comment: To be honest, i think my fit i still the best so far.